# Disable autoscale when clicking in the graph, plotly R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, click, plotly, double-click

I am using R Shiny, and on my created app, between others, I am also having a plotly graph.

My problem is that I want to disable the automatic option of autoscaling when clicking on the image. That happens by double clicking when accessing through a computer, but only by simple clicking when accessing through a mobile phone (which is the main reason I need to do this change, the people that will use it, will often need to access it through their mobile phones).

I've found this documentation
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/plotOutput.html
but it does not seem to work with plotly.
A reproducible example is given by

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)
library(rsconnect)
library(plotly)
library(stats)
library(graphics)

function(input, output) {
  x <- seq(2006,2018)
  y <- c(800,950,640,540,870,980,870,640,540,920,910,700,830)
  z <- y + 30
  qfit <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))

  output$plot <- renderPlotly ({
    plot <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_trace(x=x, y=y, type="bar", name="value") %>%
    add_trace(x=x, y=z, type="scatter", mode="markers", yaxis = 'y2', name='new') %>%
    layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", xanchor = "center",  x = 0.5),
        xaxis = list(dtick=1),
        yaxis = list(title = "Price", side = 'left', range = c(500,1200), showgrid=FALSE),
        yaxis2 = list(title = "Score", side = 'right', overlaying = "y", range = c(500,1200), showgrid=FALSE))
    plot
  })
}
```

(server.R file),

and

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)
library(rsconnect)
library(plotly)
library(stats)
library(graphics)
library(shinythemes)

renderUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),
                   titlePanel(div(HTML(""))),
                   mainPanel(
                     plotlyOutput("plot")
                     )))
```

(ui.R file).

This produces the graph, but if I replace

```
plotlyOutput("plot")
```

by

```
plotlyOutput("plot", dblclick = FALSE)
```

in order to disable the double click effect,
I get the error:

> Error : unused argument (dblclick = FALSE)

In case that has to do with the libraries masking functions between each other, the libraries I am using are:
shiny, RMySQL, rsconnect, plotly, stats, graphics, plyr, DBI, sparklyr, graphics, shinythemes, stats
although I doubt if that's the case.

Can anyone help me on that?

I would appreciate it!

Thank you anyway,

Giannis

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? It would be easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that; it's my 2nd question in the forum, I have to get used to providing a reproducible example always. I did that now.